# dplyr's summarize_all() with approx()

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm trying to get dplyr's `summarize_all()` to work with `approx()`. More concrete, the data frame `df` is to be interpolated to height_target:

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- tibble(height = c(0, 10, 20),
             a = c(1, 3, 5),
             b = c(4, 6, 8))
height_target <- c(5, 15)
```

For the one column (for example column `a`), the commands works like this:

```
approx(x = df$height, y = df$a, xout = height_target)
# $x
# [1]  5 15
# 
# $y
# [1] 2 4
```

I was able to wrap it with `summarize()`, which produces what I want but
only for one column:

```
summarize(df, h = list(height_target),
       a = list(approx(x = height, y = a, xout = height_target)$y)) %>%
  unnest()
# # A tibble: 2 x 2
#       h     a
#   <dbl> <dbl>
# 1     5     2
# 2    15     4
```

To apply it to all columns, I would do something like

```
summarize_all(df,
   funs(list(approx(x = height, y = ., xout = height_target)$y))
)
```

This, however, gives the error

> Error in summarise_impl(.data, dots) :
>    Evaluation error: 'x' and 'y' lengths differ.

I would guess that `'x'` and `'y'` of the error above are not the arguments of `approx()`. `.` should be a single column as the following commands work just fine.

```
summarize_all(df, funs(length(.)))
# # A tibble: 1 x 3
#   height     a     b
#    <int> <int> <int>
# 1      3     3     3

dfs <- summarize_all(df, funs(list(.)))
dfs$height
# [[1]]
# [1]  0 10 20
dfs$a
# [[1]]
# [1] 1 3 5
dfs$b
# [[1]]
# [1] 4 6 8
```

Any idea what the error of the summarize_all() could be? I use dplyr 0.72.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `summarise_all`, the function you specify applies in each variable. In your case, you are trying to apply the function to variable `height` as well. To get it to work I, d use `gather` first, i.e.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
 gather(var, val, -height) %>% 
 group_by(var) %>% 
 summarise(h = list(height_target), a = list(approx(x = height, y = val, xout = height_target)$y)) %>% 
 unnest() %>% 
 spread(var, a)
```

Which gives

> ```
> # A tibble: 2 x 3
>       h     a     b
> * <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
> 1     5     2     5
> 2    15     4     7
> ```

If you want to use a `summarise_*` variant, then you should use `summarise_at` not `.*_all` since you want to exclude `height` from being variable (i.e. it should be fixed for both `a` and `b` vars), i.e.

```
df %>% 
 summarise_at(vars(-height), funs(list(approx(x = height, y = ., xout = height_target)$y))) %>% 
 unnest()
```

which gives,

> ```
> # A tibble: 2 x 2
>       a     b
>   <dbl> <dbl>
> 1     2     5
> 2     4     7
> ```

As you correctly commented, you can use `summarise_all` to also include the `height` i.e.

```
df %>% 
 summarise_all(funs(list(approx(x = df$height, y = ., xout = height_target)$y))) %>% 
 unnest()
```

giving,

> ```
> # A tibble: 2 x 3
>   height     a     b
>    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
> 1      5     2     5
> 2     15     4     7
> ```

Comment: Yes, `height` would be interpolated as well, which, however, should also work: `approx(x = df$height, y = df$height, xout = height_target)`. This is why I omitted the `list(height_target)` in `summarize_all()`. Also, I would love to understand the `*_all` commands better so I would like to see a solution with `summarize_all` or understand why it is not possible. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Thanks for your new proposal. Now I understand that my command was fine in principle and also interpolating `height` _is fine_. Actually, it is too fine because interpolating `height` produces a new column in the result of the same name. When `summarize_all` wants to work on next column `a`, it uses the newly created `height` column and not the original column as intended. Thus, simply referring to df produces the correct result: `summarize_all(df, funs(list(approx(x = df$height, y = ., xout = height_target)$y))) %>% unnest()`. Could you integrate this into your answer or should I do this?